# Authenticating and uploading to various Google Drive accounts in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a C# Winforms app to connect to Google Drive, working in Visual Studio 2013.

I downloaded the Nuget packages, and created a test project using the sample code on the Google Developer page, and it works! I had to go and create my secret and keys etc, and all that went smoothly.

It uploaded my test text file to my Google Drive account. Great. 
On the initial upload of course, the authentication opened a browser window where I had to grant my application rights to access Google Drive, all of which is fine.

However I then wanted to be able to upload the test file to a different Google Drive account. However no matter what I do, this test code will ONLY upload to my default Google Drive account which is one of three which I access from my PC.
I've tried opening Google Drive in my browser, signing off my main account, signing onto another account, and WHILE THAT BROWSER IS OPEN running my test code ... but it still insistently will only upload to my same, default Google Drive.

How do I 'select' the Google Drive account I want to log onto with my code?

I understand that it is about connecting to the 'authenticated account' but I authenticate with a different Google Drive account on my PC and it makes no difference.

My test code sample is below. Please can someone shed some light on this ?

On the 8th line of the sample below, where I initialise the credentials, I thought that if I replaced the "user" string with the email address of the destination Google Drive account I want, that it would upload to that account, but it doesn't care what I put in here.

```
UserCredential credential;

        using (var filestream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json",
            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(filestream).Secrets,
                new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("DriveCommandLineSample")).Result;
        }

        // Create the service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "BackupApp",
        });

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        body.Title = "My document 4";
        body.Description = "A test document 4";
        body.MimeType = "text/plain";

        byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document4.txt");
        System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
        request.Upload();

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;
```

Comment: I haven't done this in a few years but I think deleting the client_secrets.json file will trigger a re-auth.

Comment: Thanks, but the client_secrets.json file is my applications credentials for authenticating with the Google server, not the users credentials ? Part of the setup for this sample code on the tutorial was downloading the client_secrets file from Google and ensuring it is in your code folder. Also, deleting that file would cause this filestream to throw an exception ?

Comment: Okay so I eventually figured it out myself ! The library stores a security token in a json file in the location : %AppData%\Roaming\DriveCommandLineSample for the sample code above. Once you've authenticated once, it will forever more use this token to authenticate again. The only way to change the Drive user which the system logs onto is to go in and delete or rename or move the json token file in this location ! So there you go .... it just shows in desperation if you Google enough the answer presents itself .... :)